# Starting from the last index when inserting data to MySQL while Scraping

Tags: python, mysql, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping a website and inserting data in a MySQL DB at the same time. Something like this.I had to delete the scraping portions or the code would be too big.

```
def get_page(links):
    parent_window = driver.current_window_handle
    for link in links:
        driver.execute_script('window.open(arguments[0]);', link)
        all_windows = driver.window_handles
        child_window = [window for window in all_windows if window != parent_window][0]
        driver.switch_to.window(child_window)

            #scraping


        try:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Investors(name, tags, website, introduction) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)", (name,tag,website,introduction,))
        except Exception as e:
            raise e



        parent_window1 = driver.current_window_handle
        for lin in team_div:
            driver.execute_script('window.open(arguments[0]);', lin)
            all_windows = driver.window_handles
            child_window1 = [window for window in all_windows if window != parent_window1][1]
            driver.switch_to.window(child_window1)
            time.sleep(2)
            #scraping
            driver.close()
            driver.switch_to.window(parent_window1)
            sql = cursor.execute(f"SELECT inv_id FROM Investors WHERE name =\'{name}\'")
            pid = cursor.fetchone()
            try:
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO team_members(inv_id,mem_name, picture, experience) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)", (pid,port_name,headshot, work_ex,))
            except:
                pass


        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,2825)", "")
        time.sleep(2)
            #scraping
            try:
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO portfolio(inv_id,port_name, port_icon, port_desc) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)", (pid1,p_name, p_icon, p_short_des,))
            except:
                pass

        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(parent_window)

def get_links(page):
    if page == 1:
        url = 'https://www.cypherhunter.com/en/search/?q=investments'
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(2)
        links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="app-item-container"]//a')
        return links
    else:
        url = f'https://www.cypherhunter.com/en/search/page/{page}/?q=investments'
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(2)
        links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="app-item-container"]//a')
        return links


for p in range(1, 48):
    z = get_links(p)
    get_page(z)
```

I have a sense that maybe this is a inefficient way of sending data, but then it would become two questions. My question is how can I make it so that if the script fails for some reason..it starts from the same place on the next run. The last index we can get from the `MySQL` but how to do it in the code. Only manually?

Comment: Why not utilize `try...except` to allow the script to continue running past any exeption?

Comment: I meant like, if the internet fails or something. This is a selenium based scraper since, I have to click buttons, open windows, switch windows, then close, come back to the previous window etc...so it will have to run for like 3-4 days. :(

Comment: make a script that inserts the links into the db and another one that processes them. That way you can keep track of which ones are finished.